# Why is method returning false despite condition for true being met?

Tags: java, recursion, while-loop

I am confused why it is returning false despite "total" being 1. I am aware the program will run infinitely if total = 1 is not met, but even though it is met, it returns false.
The program is supposed to split the integers of a number, square it and add it together. It should continue doing so until the result is 1.

Example:

23 = 2^2+3 ^2 = 13

13 = 1^2 + 3 ^2 = 10

10 = 1^2 + 0^2 = 1

```
class HappyNumber {

public static boolean find(int num) {

int total = 0;
while (num > 0) {
int first = num % 10;
System.out.println(first);
total += first * first;
System.out.println("total: " + total);
System.out.println("num: " + num);
num /= 10;
}

if (total == 1) {
  System.out.println("outside the loop total is: " + total);
  return true;
} 
  find(total);
  return false;

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println(HappyNumber.find(23));

    }

  }

 Output:
 3
 total: 9
 num: 23
 2
 total: 13
 num: 2
 3
 total: 9
 num: 13
 1
 total: 10
 num: 1
 0
 total: 0
 num: 10
 1
 total: 1
 num: 1
 outside the loop total is: 1
 false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the first call of the method were outside the if, so the first call will return false.

To fix that, you need to return find(number) instead of false:

```
public static boolean find(int num) {
    int total = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        int first = num % 10;
        System.out.println(first);
        total += first * first;
        System.out.println("total: " + total);
        System.out.println("num: " + num);
        num /= 10;
    }

    if (total == 1) {
        System.out.println("outside the loop total is: " + total);
        return true;
    }
//  find(total);
//  return false;
    return find(total);
}
```

Comment: It returns true, but there is StackOverflowError as the recursion continues despite returning true

Comment: the stack overflow is for which input?

Comment: StackOverflowError happening when an recursion is calling itself too many times. If you don't need recursion, don't use it.

Comment: the input is 23. output is true but recursion also continues causing the error.

Comment: are you sure you copied correctly? its not happening to me

Comment: you marked this answer as accepted, is this still throw StackOverflowError?

Comment: nope. I forgot to comment out 12 when I ran the program. It works with 23! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After the initial call from main, the method will execute its loop and then call find(total) recursively because total is not equal to 1. The loop will run again and total will not be equal to 1, so find(total) is called recursively again. That's *two* recursive calls, so you have two frames pushed on to the stack. At the second recursive call, total evaluates to 1 and the method returns true and one frame is popped from the stack. *But*, there is still another frame on the stack which must unroll and it duly does returning false.